# wildfly stops at setting java property when running standalone.bat

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly, web-deployment, wildfly-8

I am trying to deploy my application on wildfly, my version is 8.2.1. However when I run standalone.bat file in the bin folder, I get the following two lines and then the batch process stops.

```
>C:\dev\wildfly\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "C:\dev\wildfly\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\bin\java"

>C:\dev\wildfly\bin>
```

I am not sure how to debug it as I do not get any error, I would really appreciate it if you can help me with this.

Comment: Check if your environment has a JAVA_OPTS setting that is conflicting with Wildfly.  Mine are currently set to:  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms256m -Xmx3000m via _JAVA_OPTIONS setting under System Properties > Environment Variables dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have no variale in my system environment variables named JAVA_OPTS, should i add one? where should it link to?

Answer (score 3):

Wildfly is trying to run java.exe in your Java path. 
In your case, `JAVA_HOME` is given as  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin`. Wildfly will append `\bin\java` to call java.exe. So finally it will becomes `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\bin\java`. This doesn't exist. So the standalone exits.

What you should do is:
change `JAVA_HOME` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_65` (just remove the `\bin` at the end) in your environment variables. Then standalone should work.